# Issue with Jquery autocomplete looks

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using [Jquery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html). Its workng fine but I have small problem. Button next to input box appears bit larger.
[image]
I want button to be of same height as of input box. I checked applied css but couldnt find any height attribute for button.
Even on the official site I observed that that buttons height is bit smaller than input.
[image]

How can I change its height to make it same as input ?
**EDIT:**
I added following style

```
<style>
.comboButton {
    height:20px;
    valign:bottom;
}

</style>
```

[image]

Its height have changed but not able to bring it down. I tried `padding:bottom=0px` and `valign="bottom"` but no luck.

Comment: try also vertical-align:baseline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use firebug to check classnames and id's, you can see it's:

```
.ui-widget button {
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    top:15px;

}
```

If you don't want it to any other ui-buttons,

```
#myContainer .ui-widget button {
    //
}
```

Comment: I checked it but couldnt find `height` attribute. I found `button.ui-button-icon-only {
    width: 2.4em;
}`

Comment: I tried both `margin-top:15px` and `vertical-align:baseline` but no luck. Both input and button moving together even I changed ones `margin-top`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. Enjoying hoilday now will update you on monday :)